# Input field for accepting mobile numbers

Tags: html, validation, bootstrap-4

I want to get mobile number as input of different countries.
I tried using below code:

```html
<input type="tel" minlength="8" maxlength="10" name="Number" id="Number" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="* WhatsApp Number" required/>
```

But it also accepts characters, so how can i apply **length validation** and **number validation**.

Comment: It applies both. If you type a character and leave the field, the element's `validity.valid` property is set to `false`, its `validity.patternMismatch` property is set to `true` and the CSS pseudo-class `:invalid` is enabled.

Comment: what should be my pattern, cause with this pattern numbers are not getting accepted ?

Comment: If you click Run code snippet, you'll see you can type numbers in there all you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input text field that only accepts numbers AND the dash character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785288/input-text-field-that-only-accepts-numbers-and-the-dash-character)

Comment: Arguably it should accept the `+` character as it is the standard for indicating an international dialing code. EXTENSIVE discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745545/is-there-a-standard-for-phone-numbers

Comment: @HereticMonkey That js code doesn't accept + or ( ).

Comment: I have specified that i want to accept different countries mobile numbers so that does include + and ( ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will prevent character to be typed. While typing anything except numbers are omitted.

```html
<input type="tel" required minlength="8" maxlength="15" name="Number" id="Number"  class="form-control wow fadeInUp" placeholder="* WhatsApp Number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9+()]/g, '');" pattern=".{8,10}" placeholder="123-45-678" />
```

Comment: I've formatted your code for you, but you should explain any changes you've made to the code, or how the code answers the OP's question, as text accompanying the code.

Comment: check now @HereticMonkey

Comment: @ king neo how do i add regex to accept + and ( ) with numbers ?

Comment: Now it accepts + and () but nullifies the length validation, even less than 8 digits also gets accepted.

Comment: check not but you can use js validation also

Comment: happy coding :) :)